# No declaration found for element 'location'

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have generated the .net.xml, .poly.xml and .rou.xml from sumo. I use Veina-4a2, when I imported them on my machine which its operating system is Windows, I got this error when I executed the simulation:

```
<status>
    <exit-code>1</exit-code>
    <start>1478098091</start>
    <end>1478098093</end>
    <status>Exited with error code 1</status>
    <stdout><![CDATA[Loading configuration... done.
]]></stdout>
    <stderr><![CDATA[Error: no declaration found for element 'location'
 In file 'scenario.poly.xml'
 At line/column 27/226.

Quitting (on error).
]]></stderr>
</status>
```

Knowing that I run the same example with my other linux machine and it works well.
I need to execute the example in both machines, so can you help me please?
Here attached the first lines of my scenario.poly.xml:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simulation seems to use an outdated schema to validate the input file. Please check whether you have the SUMO_HOME environment variable defined and whether it points to the correct installation dir. You can add also the option --xml-validation never to the sumo call (or rather insert  into the sumo cfg).

Comment: Thank you for your help Michael, I solved the problem: the SUMO_HOME environment variable was not defined.